# backend module executed while starting python flask server app

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Python Flask and Python.
I use Python 3.7 and Ubuntu.

I have done export FLASK_APP=emptst 
And have been executing an online application. It was running fine

In the same environment I have a pure python program & I executed it from command prompt.
I think while executing this the python flask server was listening. It is a localhost server
After this I have stopped the server and ran the python online again.The server came up But it started executing the python program that I executed from command line. 
And when I removed the program from the mflask directory it is giving the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ss/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/ss/mflask/emptst_new.py", line 2, in <module>
    import recognize_faces_video_file1_200119
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'recognize_faces_video_file1_200119'
```

Pls advise. Basically i need it to run the online application emptst and not execute the batch application which it executes currently, whenever i start the server

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/ Please go through this for the deployment options of a flask app

Comment: is `recognize_faces_video_file1_200119` really a python module? You should look up `ModuleNotFoundError` and find out how to fix it.